# How to telnet google using command prompt?

Tags: telnet

This is what I tried

```
telnet www.google.com 80

Get   HTTP/1.1  Host:www.google.com
```

This I what I receive back

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 925
Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2012 19:37:42 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
```

How do I make this work? I trying to use telnet to access  www.google.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544857/how-to-telnet-google-using-command-prompt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 173.194.38.82...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.jp/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[.... skipped ....]
```

Comment: Seems like it is working. The return message gets truncated in the command prompt, how do I view the whole thing?

Comment: @developer747 You should put `Host: www.google.com` on the separate line. I can see the whole page, starting from `<!doctype html>` and ending in `</script></body></html>` with bunch of script code in between.

Comment: a little description would help to answer questions.

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro if you have a question, feel free to ask. preferably as a separate question.

Comment: Would love a better description.

Answer (score 9):

After issuing the request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

you also need input **an empty line** to show that your request has ended, otherwise, nothing will be returned.

Reference: http://blog.nullspace.io/day-208.html

Comment: "Empty line" is important.